# Java failed to bootstrap path, eclipse, jdk-13

Tags: eclipse, javafx, java-14, module-path

I’m trying to update my JavaFX project to be compatible with JRE 13 (until now it was set up to use JRE 1.8). I’m developing with Eclipse 2020-03, using a Mac.

The first big issue I’ve had to deal with is the migration from the included JavaFX libraries in JDK 1.8 to having to import JavaFX (14) as an external package for JDK 13.

The second issue is migration from using the classpath to using the modulepath. I’m new to the module path, so what I say about it may not make sense, but my current setup now is this:

```
modulepath:
    <list of other .jar files>
    JRE System Library [Java SE 13 [13.0.2]]
    JavaFX 14
        <list of .jar files I downloaded, including javafx-swt, javafx.base, javafx.controls, javafx.fxml, javafx.graphics, javafx.media, javafx.swing, javafx.web>
        <I created a User Library from the above listed .jar’s>
```

*Finally*, all the compiler errors are now gone (I had to recompile some of the external .jar files I downloaded so there weren’t any split packages), but when I build and run the application class nothing happens.

Checking the Mac system console, the below output seems to reference why the app is not starting, but I checked he JDK path and the referenced `java` executable does exist.

```
com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.xpc.launchd.domain.pid.java.40558): Failed to bootstrap path: path = /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-13.0.2.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java, error = 2: No such file or directory
```

What is happening here? If you need more info about my project config, comment and I can add details.